# Does the number of columns have to be the same as in regression model when making predictions?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, prediction

I have made a linear regression model with a data set that contains more columns that are actually needed in the regression. However, the columns are named in a proper manner. When I make the prediction with a predict() function, does something go wrong if I use a testing data set with multiple columns with some of them not used in the model? Or does the predict function make predictions based on the column names which are matching for both the testing and training data set?

Comment: This might depend on the specific model. However, the best way to know for sure it's to try. Just train a model and check its predictions on a new dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not doing anything bizarre, this should be fine.

```r
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(z = rnorm(101), x = rnorm(101), y = rnorm(101), q = rnorm(101))
## use a subset of the columns in the model
m1 <- lm(z ~ x + y, data = dd)
```

New data: different order, extraneous columns:

```r
pd <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), x = rnorm(10))
predict(m1, newdata = pd)
```

The only case where you'll be in trouble is if you have predictors in your original model that are **not** included in your prediction (`newdata`) set.

As @nicola comments, unless you're worried about something subtle going wrong, the best way to find out is to try it with an experiment like the one above.